# Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ɵmod')

Tags: angular13

I have migrated my application from Angular version 9 to 13. After a lot of caveats I reached to ng serve it without any error in Angular CLI. Now, as soon as my application launches in browser, I see below provided error.

I tried different solutions provided by different communities; like; stackoverflow, github etc. but unfortunately no luck so far. I tried below suggestions:

- Delete node_modules, delete package.lock.json, clear the npm cache, clear the .angular cache, restart VS code, do npm i, ng serve.
- Check for circular dependency in application and resolve it.
- If you are using custom pipe in application, don't mention them in imports of ngModule, mention them in providers.

[image: Error Image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot !!!

**Package.json & tsconfig.json**
[image]

Comment: please include the code as text in your question rather than as screenshots

Answer (score 1):

If you are lazy loading in app-routing, then use return keyword in your module import syntax like below:

[image]

This solution could be specific to Angular 12 or higher.